# in Scala : Generic trait with companion object trait?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given this:

```
trait TraitClass[A <: TraitObject] {
   def name = A.getName // <-- How ???
}

trait TraitObject[A <: TraitClass] {
   def apply: A
   def getName: String
}

case class Foo(a: Int) extends TraitClass[Foo] {

}

object Foo extends TraitObject[Foo] {
   def getName = "foo"
   def apply = Foo(12)
}
```

Is there a way to make that work in a more Scala way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
abstract class TraitClass(obj: TraitObject[_]) {
   def name = obj.getName
}

trait TraitObject[A <: TraitClass] {
   def apply: A
   def getName: String
}

case class Foo(a: Int) extends TraitClass(Foo) {

}

object Foo extends TraitObject[Foo] {
   def getName = "foo"
   def apply = Foo(12)
}
```

Passing the `Companion Object` as input of the class trait allow you to use it.

Running example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/D2GrOHIiQM6KcUMAYHjuuw

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your use case very much. For example

```
  trait TraitClass[A <: TraitObject[_]] {
    def getA: A
    def name: String = getA.getName
  }

  trait TraitObject[A <: TraitClass[_]] {
    def apply: A
    def getName: String
  }

  case class Foo(a: Int) extends TraitClass[Foo.type] {
    def getA = Foo
  }

  object Foo extends TraitObject[Foo] {
    def getName = "foo"
    def apply = Foo(12)
  }
```